# reading a file in cp819 encoding

Tags: python, python-2.7, decoding

I have a file (downloaded from somewhere on the www) that is encoded in CP819, and want to read it then further handle the data in UTF-8. Tried all the examples I could find here and elsewhere, nothing worked.

The furthest I could get:

```
with codecs.open(INFIL, mode='rb',encoding='cp819') as INPUT:
 DUMMY=INPUT.readline()
 print (DUMMY)
```

which gave me

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe8' in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

At offset 5 in the input file is the first character above ascii 128: the \xe8 is supposed to decode to 'è'.

Found a few pages concerning this error message, tried all suggestions I found, nothing helps.

Using python 2.7.6 on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly encode the unicode string using [`unicode.encode`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode):

```
with codecs.open(INFIL, encoding='cp819') as f:
    line = line.readline()
    print line.encode('utf-8')
```

Another way is to invoke the python program with the environment `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8` set.

```
PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 python /path/to/python_program.py
```

Comment: Well, it was a good answer to my first issue, but I immediately came upon a new one. Not sure whether to continue here or to start a new question - the issue is still related to decoding an input file.

Comment: @Karlchen9, Please a post a separated question.

Comment: @Karlchen9, post a question as an answer is not welcome in stackoverflow community.

Comment: @Karlchen9, To answer your new question shortly, you should not use `codecs.open` if you are dealing with binary data, and decode manually for the text lines.